# Send a command via MVVMLight

Tags: mvvm-light

I am using MVVMLight and going through a little of a learning curve to try and work out how communication works. I understand how Properties work together with Silverlight binding and that's all quite straight-forward.

Now what I want to know is what is the best approach for sending a Message as a Command. So for example I want to send a message to my ViewModel to erase its list.

So I could create an enum to act as a command

```
enum MessageOp
{
    Reset
}
```

But then how could I send this as a command? At the moment I send it as the class, but then need to send it again as the token. Like so:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<MessageOp>(MessageOp.Reset, MessageOp.Reset);
```

With my code in the ViewModel like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MessageOp>(
    this, MessageOp.Reset,
    delegate(MessageOp op)
    {
        // Erase all entries
        MyDictionary.Clear();
    });
```

One way I thought of was creating a totally empty class to act as a command. Would this be the best approach as I feel a bit odd creating empty classes to act like this

Comment: did the answer fit your needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure what you trying to achive, but I guess you want to send a message from one view to another. In this case you use

```
Messenger.Send(Message.Reset);
```

to send the message. On the recipient side you use the following code:

```
Messenger.Register<MessageOp>(this, (m) => {
    if (m == MessageOp.Reset) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Very important: If you use messaging be sure to remove the recipient from the Messenger. In case of a view model this can be done by calling Cleanup on the view model. In all other cases use Messenger.Unregister(recipient). This is necessary as the weak action implementation in MVVM Light has a known problem releasing the recipient on its own.

However, if you just wanted to bind a button (or something similar) to a command, you use a RelayCommand.

Add the following definition to your view model:

```
public RelayCommand ResetCommand {
    get {
        return _resetCommand ?? (_resetCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () => { 
                // your execution code
            },
            () => {
                // can execute - gets called quite often!
            )
        ));
    }
}
private RelayCommand _resetCommand;
```

Then you can bind this command to a button

```
<button Content="Reset" Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"/>
```

**Edit**

To send a message to a specific recipient, there are really two possibilities:

1. Add a token when you are sending the message.
2. Create a custom message that only the recipient subscribes to.

Personally, I'd go for the second approach as it is more clear and explicit - and therefore more maintainable. So, to create a custom Message you can do the following:

```
public class OperationMessage : GenericMessage<MessageOp> {
    public OperationMessage(MessageOp operation) : base(operation) { }
}

public class ResetMessage : OperationMessage 
{
    public ResetMessage() : base(MessageOp.Reset) { }
}
```

Now you can send

```
Messenger.Send(new ResetMessage());
```

and receive

```
Messenger.Register<ResetMessage>(this, (m) => {
    // do your resetting here
});
```

or

```
Messenger.Register<OperationMessage>(this, true, (m) => {
    // handle all operations here - the operation is avaiable via m.Content
});
```

The reason why I'd create the OperationMessage is that it is more flexible, and lets you handle your operations genericly or specificly, as need be.

Comment: It's not quite what I was looking for but is useful information none the less. What I wanted was to send a message and ensure it went to a specific target. Thinking about it more I guess I could use a string target with a name of what it is I am wanting to receive and then register against that token. Such as `Messenger.Default.Send<MessageOp>(MessageOp.Reset, "PeopleViewModel");` One small thing, at what point should one Cleanup as you say you should? Is this at destructor or some other point?

Comment: @Firedragon see edit ... hope this solves your problem. Being more specific in your OP would have helped ... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough. Trying to word questions in such a way as not totally explaining what I am doing at work is proving a challenge :-) One last thing, would you mind explaining a little more at which stage the Cleanup needs to be done (obviously destructors don't exist, I went all C++ for a moment)

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702103/mvvm-light-messenger-executing-multiple-times/6341069#6341069) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540139/navigationpage-is-incremented-for-each-hyperlinkbutton-click-silverlight/6541524#6541524) for some details, generally on the VM that receives the call call Cleanup once messaging is no longer needed or the VM is destroyed. On Views follow the advice in one of the posts. Hope this helps ... :-)